# haproxy backend configuration using one hostname with multiple IP addresses

Tags: backend, haproxy, hostname

I am using the following configuration fragment

```
backend test_http_back
   balance roundrobin
   server some_hostname host.somesite.com:8080 check
```

host.somesite.com has two IP addresses in the DNS

Ideally I would put

```
backend test_http_back
   balance roundrobin
   server host_A u.x.y.z:8080 check    
   server host_A a.b.c.d:8080 check
```

However the IP addresses are not static which raises a second question, is the hostname only resolved when the configuration is loaded? This is not too much of an issue as I control when the IPs change and can reload haproxy's configuration. Having to change the configuration file each time the IPs change is more problematic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and, being somewhat new to HAProxy, am not familiar with the "right way" to configure the backend to manage it.  Based on limited experience, the behavior we've witnessed is that HAProxy resolves the backend server hostname at startup, selecting the IP address that is first on the list from the DNS server.  In our case, the hostname resolves to three IP addresses, one of which is "bad".  If the "bad" IP happens to be selected by HAProxy at startup, hits on the frontend get returned with a 503/NOSRV error and HAProxy makes no attempt to re-resolve the hostname or try one of the other IPs received earlier in order to make a successful backend connection.  Our only workaround in this situation is to reload (or restart) the HAProxy service in order to hopefully pick up a "working" IP address.

I'm hoping that there's a configuration setting available on the backend that could manage this situation automatically?

Comment: Hey Allen, same thing here now. Did you manage to solve the problem?